# Why are my scripts not added to a react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-helmet

I am trying to add js scripts (that are fully functional) to a react project. I know its not best practice but lets say i have to do it. I tried to add them using useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "./js/app.js";
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  }
}, []);
```

and using react helmet:

```
export const Script = () => {
    return(
        <Helmet>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
        </Helmet>
    )
}

export default Script;
```

But in both version the scripts don't work.

My app.js:

```
$(function() {
    var $body = $('body');


    //----------  Close on click Outside of Container
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function clickOutsideContainer(selector, container, callback) {
        selector.on('mouseup', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    };

    //----------  Modal
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function modal() {
        var modalInit = $('.js-modal-init');
        var modalInner = $('.js-modal-inner');
        var modalSel = $('.js-modal');
        var modalShowClass = 'is-visible';

        modalInit.on('click', function() {
            modalSel.addClass(modalShowClass);
        });

        function closeModal() {
            modalSel.removeClass(modalShowClass);
        };

        clickOutsideContainer($body, modalInner, closeModal);
    }

    modal();

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by “don’t work”? Do they throw an error? Does anything happen?

Comment: It's just that their functionalities didn't get implemented.

Comment: Can you see the script elements? Just because the functionalities don’t seem to happen doesn’t mean nothing does.

Comment: Not sure how I am suppose to check that. When I inspected the page I didn't find the mentioned scripts though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you invoke the code inside your script

```
(function () {
...
})();
```

Comment: Good point. Just because scripts are added doesn’t mean the JavaScript functions will be run

Comment: I think I did, added the app.js file to the question.

Comment: In all honesty I am quite new to react so there is a strong possibility I am making a dumb mistake.